# ReactJS:setState could not work in Syncfusion React Toast

Tags: reactjs, toast, syncfusion

I using Syncfusion React Toast with singnalr for showing popup notification to user. but after fetch data from server with signalr and set message state with fetched value, toast content shows initial value which it`s assigned in constructor function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToastComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-notifications';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';


class Notification extends ToastComponent {

        constructor() {
            super(...arguments);
            this.position = { X: 'Right', Y: 'Top' }
            this.state = { message: '555'}

        }

        toastCreated() {
            this.toastInstance.show({ timeOut: 0 })

        }

        componentDidMount() {
            const notifConn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/notif").build();

            notifConn.on("ReceiveMessage",(msg) => {
                this.setState({ message: msg });
            });
            notifConn.start().then(function () {
                notifConn.invoke("SendNotification");

            }).catch(function (er) {
                console.log(er.toString());
            });

        }


        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <ToastComponent 
                       id='toast_target'
                       ref={toast => this.toastInstance = toast}
                       title={this.state.message}//it shows 555!!!
                       content={this.state.message} //it shows 555!!!
                       position={this.position}    
                       showCloseButton
                       created={this.toastCreated = this.toastCreated.bind(this)}
                    />

                </div>
                   );
        }
    }

    export default Notification;
```

Comment: Is `notifConn.on` is executed? Are you able to print `msg` inside?

Comment: yes...console.log() printed msg

Comment: Try this `this.setState({ message: msg }, () => console.log(this.state.message))`, If it print new state, then your setState is working properly and problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings from Syncfusion support.

By default, we couldn’t modify the content dynamically for existing displaying toasts. Dynamically changed content will be shown on notify the next toasts.

So, we suggest you to hide the previous toast and show the next toast after setState.

Please find the below code for your reference.

**Chat.js**

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
    message: '',
};
componentDidMount = () => {
    const nick = window.prompt('Your name:', 'John');

    const hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:5000/chat');

    this.setState({ hubConnection, nick }, () => {
        …………..
        this.state.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', (nick, receivedMessage) => {
            this.setState({ message: receivedMessage }); // Change the toast content using state
            this.toastObj.hide(); // You can hide the toast
            this.toastObj.show(); // You can show the toast
        });
    });
};

create = () => {
    this.toastObj.show({ timeOut: 0 });
}

<ToastComponent ref={ (toast) => { this.toastObj = toast; } } content = { this.state.message } id = 'toast_default' created = { this.create.bind(this) } > </ToastComponent>
```

We have created sample for an ASP.NET core signalr with the react toast component.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/AspNetCoreSignalRToastReact1983063835

Please find the below steps to run the above sample.

- Navigate inside of AspNetCoreSignalR_React.Client folder and enter
  ‘npm install’.
- Start the client app by entering ‘npm start’.
- Run the AspNetCoreSignalR_React.Server project.

If the above solution doesn’t meet your requirement, kindly send the below details.

- Have any reason on using static toasts with dynamic content update?

Regards,

Narayanasamy P.